# Sync views from Local datatbase to tables SQL Azure Database

Tags: azure-sql-database

Can we sync views on local database with tables on SQL azure database using SQL Azure Datat Sync[Preview]? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the jury is still out on SQL Azure Data Sync. It's been in preview for years and still is.

When you say sync, and you looking to take the results of a local view and persist them as a table in SQL Azure?

If so, you can create a SELECT INTO, taking the data from the local view and letting the SELECT INTO make a table out of it. There are some things you need do to make the SQL Azure DB available locally:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336282.aspx

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59328/insert-to-sql-azure-through-linked-server-very-slow